# Using Dirichlet's hyperbola method and Dirichlet's formula

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

[Dirichlet Hyperbola Method](http://planetmath.org/dirichlethyperbolamethod).  For $x \geq 2$:

$$ \sum_{n \leq x} \frac{d(n)}{n} = \frac{1}{2} \log^2 x + 2\gamma \log x + \gamma^2 + O(\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}})$$

I know already that the summation of 1/n can be written $\log x + \gamma + O(1/x)$ and summation of $d(n)$ can be written $$ \sum_{n \leq x} d(n) = x \log x+(2 \gamma-1)x + O(\sqrt{x})$$ if this helps?

Comment: It says *mimic* proof, so you should start drawing the same hyperbola and counting points under it in several different ways, except now you will be dividing each `d(n)` by `n` instead of the whole thing.  These are really cute results, fun stuff, assuming your teacher is thinking along the same lines I do on these.

Comment: Well I don't think that's the route he would suggest. I think Abel's Identity could be it. Someone commented earlier and then deleted the comment. Thanks anyways kcrisman. I have no rep yet to give anyone points. I am new.

Comment: I have no idea what question you're trying to ask.

Comment: @kcrisman You say "It says mimic proof".   *What* says that?   This question, and all the comments and answers to it, make very little sense to me; they appear to be dialogue out of context.   The link to the Planetmath article doesn't help clear it up.  Can you help explain what's going on here?

Comment: @DonHatch originally there was an image posted that had this.  It was deleted at some point since the time five years ago I made that comment.  I've submitted an edit which will hopefully resolve your comment, though I guess it will have to be approved first.

Answer (score 3):

Following the notation from the 
[Planetmath Article](http://planetmath.org/dirichlethyperbolamethod)
we note that
$$\frac{\tau(n)}{n} = 1/n * 1/n =
\sum_{d|n} \frac{1}{d} \left(\frac{n}{d}\right)^{-1}.$$

Substituting this into the formula for the method we obtain
$$\sum_{n\le x} \frac{\tau(n)}{n} =
\sum_{a\le\sqrt{x}} \sum_{b\le x/a} 
\frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{b}
+ \sum_{b\le\sqrt{x}} \sum_{a\le x/b} 
\frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{b}
- \sum_{a\le\sqrt{x}} \sum_{b\le\sqrt{x}} 
\frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{b}
\\ =
\sum_{a\le\sqrt{x}} \frac{1}{a} \sum_{b\le x/a} 
\frac{1}{b}
+ \sum_{b\le\sqrt{x}}  \frac{1}{b} \sum_{a\le x/b} 
\frac{1}{a}
- \sum_{a\le\sqrt{x}} \frac{1}{a}  \sum_{b\le\sqrt{x}} 
\frac{1}{b}
\\ =
\sum_{a\le\sqrt{x}} \frac{1}{a} (\log x - \log a + \gamma)
+ \sum_{b\le\sqrt{x}}  \frac{1}{b} (\log x - \log b + \gamma)
- (\log\sqrt{x} + \gamma)^2
\\ = 2\log x (\log\sqrt{x} + \gamma)
+ 2\gamma (\log\sqrt{x} + \gamma)
- 2 \sum_{q\le\sqrt{x}} \frac{\log q}{q}
- (\log\sqrt{x} + \gamma)^2
\\ = 2\log x (\log\sqrt{x} + \gamma)
+ \gamma^2
- 2 \sum_{q\le\sqrt{x}} \frac{\log q}{q}
- \frac{1}{4} \log^2 x
\\ = \log^2 x  + 2\gamma\log x
+ \gamma^2
- 2 \sum_{q\le\sqrt{x}} \frac{\log q}{q}
- \frac{1}{4} \log^2 x.$$

To evaluate the remaining sum term we could use the fact that
$$\left(\frac{1}{2} \log^2 x\right)' = \frac{\log x}{x}$$
but we need the constant term which is given in terms of the
[Stiltjes constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants)
as $$\sum_{q=1}^n \frac{\log q}{q} \sim
\frac{1}{2} \log^2 n + \gamma_1.$$

This finally yields the formula
$$\log^2 x  + 2\gamma\log x
+ \gamma^2
- 2 \left(\frac{1}{2} \log^2\sqrt{x} + \gamma_1\right)
- \frac{1}{4} \log^2 x
\\ = \log^2 x  + 2\gamma\log x
+ \gamma^2
- 2 \left(\frac{1}{8} \log^2 x + \gamma_1\right)
- \frac{1}{4} \log^2 x
\\ = \log^2 x  + 2\gamma\log x
+ \gamma^2
- \frac{1}{4} \log^2 x - 2\gamma_1
- \frac{1}{4} \log^2 x
\\ = \frac{1}{2} \log^2 x  + 2\gamma\log x
+ \gamma^2 - 2\gamma_1.$$

The equalities are plus implicit lower order terms.

**Addendum.** The bound on the error terms follows from the harmonic number asymptotics $H_n = \log n + \gamma + \frac{1}{2n} + \cdots$ We get from the first term $\sum_{a\le \sqrt{x}} \frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{2x/a} = \frac{1}{2x} \sum_{a\le \sqrt{x}} 1$ which is $O(1/\sqrt{x}).$ The second term is the same. The third term contributes $\log\sqrt{x} \times 1/\sqrt{x}$ which is $O(\log x/\sqrt{x}).$ We see  that the third lower order term dominates the first two, which gives exactly the formula proposed by the OP.

Comment: What is the question that you're answering?  The OP didn't actually ask a question, as far as I can see, so it looks like the two of you are conversing in a secret language.

Comment: It seems clear to me, he is asking for the initial terms of the asymptotic expansion of the sum using the hyperbola method. I am using $\tau$ for the divisor function.

Comment: Thanks, Marko.  I still feel like there is some context missing, which everyone seems to have seen except me.  See also the comment I added to the main question thread.  It feels like something has been deleted or damaged.  I wonder, did the planetmath link originally lead to more material that has since been deleted, which would make this all make more sense?

Comment: Interesting that you should point this out, I also remember the planetmath link as being quite different from what it is now, but that was many years ago.

Comment: Correct, there was an image before, and some other editing happened in the meantime.

Comment: @DonHatch unfortunately that "secret language" thing happens a lot with edits one doesn't know about.  I recommend looking through the edit history of questions where you see that happen first and try to help by rolling them back or improving the questions, though even then sometimes it's hard to decipher the history for some questions, I admit!